# forward slash in string literal behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

why do S1 and S2 behave differently with respect to apostrophe location?

```
S1="1/282/03/10"
S2="4/107/03/10"
R1="".join({"N\'" ,S1,"\'" })
R2="".join({"N\'" ,S2,"\'" })
```

Outputs:

```
"N''1/282/03/10"    //R1 
"N'4/107/03/10'"    //R2
```

Comment: Sets are unordered collection.

Comment: With the above code, you'll get a different output each time. What is the output you're after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using `set`.

> **`set` is a collection which is unordered and unindexed.**

So you have to use the following code to get the desired results,

```
S1 = "1/282/03/10"
S2 = "4/107/03/10"
R1 = "".join(["N\'", S1, "\'"])
R2 = "".join(["N\'", S2, "\'"])

print(R1)
print(R2)
```

**Output:**

```
N'1/282/03/10'
N'4/107/03/10'
```

Comment: Can't he just use R1 = "N\'" + S1 + "\'"  R2 = "N\'" + S2 + "\'"? Why the need for lists?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you wrap `"\'",S1,"'\"` in a `set`.

*set* is an unordered collection.

To avoid the above issue use `list` or `tuple`.

```
R1 = "".join(["N\'", S1, "\'"])
R2 = "".join(["N\'", S2, "\'"])

#tuple equivalent is
R1 = "".join(("N\'", S1, "\'"))
R2 = "".join(("N\'", S2, "\'"))
```

You can use `.format` here you don't even need to use `list` or `tuple`.

```
R1="N'{}'".format(S1)
R2="N'{}'".format(S2)
```

You can also use this.

```
R1 = "N\'" + S1 + "\'"
R2 = "N\'" + S2 + "\'"
```